# Table appear when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, frontend

It is possible on my web page when one of the buttons in a menu is clicked, a table will appear and when another button is clicked it will replace the table into another table with different data?

I have tried different possibilities, somehow it works but it doesn't replace the table.

```
document.getElementById("table1").style.display="none";
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("table1").style.display = "none";` just hides the element with the ID `table`. There’s no replacing going on; we’d need more context for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [need help switching between tables in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970443/need-help-switching-between-tables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("table1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("table2").style.display = "none";
});
document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("table2").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("table1").style.display = "none";
});
```

```html
<button id="btn1">button 1</button>
<button id="btn2">button 2</button>
<table id="table1" style="width:100%;display:none">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="table2" style="width:100%;display:none">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

a sample for your question is the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Appear and Disappear</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <button onclick="showTable1()">showTable1</button>
    <button onclick="showTable2()">showTable2</button>
  </nav>
  <table id='table1' style="display:none">
    <tr>
      <th>Table Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        It's table1
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <table id='table2' style="display:none">
    <tr>
      <th>Table Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        It's table2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    function showTable1() {
      document.getElementById("table1").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("table2").style.display = "none";
    } function showTable2() {
      document.getElementById("table1").style.display = "none"; document.getElementById("table2").style.display = "block";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```